# SoundManager2: How to attach a onfinish event callback of the current Playing sound

Tags: javascript, html, soundmanager2

I am using *SoundManager2* with `'ui360 / threeSixtyPlayer'` style in my HTML.
I have a table and a series of anchors with its appropriate `href` set to an audio Stream.

When the Page renders I see a series of Play buttons.
Now, the user can select any of them to play a Sound, I don't have a reference to the sound
that is playing.

I'll need a `onfinish event` so that I can update some status of the Current row which finished playing.

Is there a way to attach a `onfinish event` to the current playing sound?
Can some-one please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you checked the soundmanager documentation before asking here, but I think this looks very much as what you need:

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#sound-object-properties

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the onfinish handler at the time you create the sound:

```
var obj = soundManager.createSound({
    id: hash,
    url: '/any/url/file.mp3',
    //autoLoad: FlashDetect.installed,
    autoLoad:false, // Best response in HTML5
    volume: 10,
    autoPlay: true,
    stream: true,
    onfinish: function() {
        console.log('onfinish'); 
        // your on finish action here
    },
    onconnect: function() { 
        console.log('onconnect'); 
    },
    onload: function() {
        console.log('onload'); 
    }
    // etc
}

// This fires file.mp3, when it finishes playing will fire onfinish() 
obj.play()
```

For more handlers and other sound-instance methods good to a look at the [docs](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/).